# plot contour in different panels of sp plot

Tags: r, raster, contour, lattice, r-sp

I have 3 different rasters in a stack. I need to plot a panel plot and add different shapefiles on each panel. So far I managed to do the following;

```
    ## read the libraries
    library(raster)
    library(rgdal)
    library(sp)
    library(rworldmap)
    library(OceanView)

    ##random raster object
    r <- raster(ncol=40, nrow=20)
    r[] <- rnorm(n=ncell(r))
    # Create a RasterStack object with 3 layers
    s <- stack(x=c(r, r*2, r**2))

    ##coordinate system
    wgs<-CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs")


    ##reading the additional shape files
    w <- spTransform(getMap(), wgs)
    poly <- list(list("sp.lines", as(w, 'SpatialLines'), lwd = 
            0.5,col="black"))

    ##plotting with spplot
    plot(spplot(s,layout=c(3,1),sp.layout=poly,
                 colorkey =list(space = "right"),
                names.attr = c("a","b","c")))
```

so far I plotted the 3 rasters with a shapefile overlayed on it. Now I need to plot the 3 different contours one each on the panel plot. And also need to plot the windspeed arrows on each of the plot. I know to do this I need to use contour() and quiver() functions. However, I am unable to plot these.

```
    ## different raster stack for the contour plot
    s1 <- stack(x=c(r/2, r*10, r**5))


    ##differnt wind components
    lat= matrix(rep(seq(-90,90,length.out=20),each=20), ncol=20, byrow=TRUE)
    lon=matrix(rep(seq(-180,180,length.out=20),each=20), ncol=20, byrow=F)
    u=matrix(rep(sample(seq(-2,2,length.out=1000),20),each=20), ncol=20, byrow=TRUE)
    v=matrix(rep(sample(seq(-2,2,length.out=1000),20),each=20), ncol=20, byrow=TRUE)

    ##plot the arrows
    quiver2D(u = u,v=v,x = lon, y = lat,add=T,type="simple")
```

can any one help me with this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I wasn't clear on what a "panel plot" was supposed to be, nor could I find the function `quiver` (or `quiver2D`) in any of those packages.

Comment: @42-  Oh Sorry I didn't put all the libraries there. By panel plot I mean to say a plot with 3 columns and 1 row. Rather than plotting each raster separately, I want to combine them in a single plot and spplot has functionality for this  layout=c(3,1). Regarding the arrow plot there are different packages like pracma::quiver or OceanView::quiver2D that do the same job.

Comment: So you want multiple plots on a single page of output, perhaps to be presented in "landscape" format? And I now get an error from the `checkinput` function that gets called by `quiver2D`. Says `'x' not compatible with u or v`, perhaps because you did not test your random values after setting `set.seed()`?

Comment: I've tried a few times and am still not able to get that code in the second block to run without error.

Comment: @42- error was due to mismatch of the rows and columns. I corrected it and it should work now. Can you let me know if you can plot with out error?

Comment: I don't get any plot from the quiver2D call, probably because of the add=T, but I do get a warning thrown by the arrow function. The `quiver3D` function is using base graphics, while `spplot` is using `lattice` graphics so you will need to use something like the gridBase package. to get them in the same paradigm.

Comment: @42- Thanks. Just leave the arrow plot for now. Can you just show me how can I add contour plot (using the raster stack(s1)) to each of the panels of the plot?

Answer (score 1):

First you need to figure out which function in the lattice paradigm is  being called. That requires either looking at the ?spplot` help page (which I stupidly failed to do first), or following the classes and functions along the calling tree (which is what I actually did). And then look at the help page of the final function to see if there is a parameter you can pass to add contour lines:

```
showMethods("spplot",class="Raster", includeDefs=TRUE) # last argument need to see code
Function: spplot (package sp)
obj="Raster"
function (obj, ...) 
{
    .local <- function (obj, ..., maxpixels = 50000, as.table = TRUE, 
        zlim) 
    {
        obj <- sampleRegular(obj, maxpixels, asRaster = TRUE, 
            useGDAL = TRUE)
        if (!missing(zlim)) {
            if (length(zlim) != 2) {
                warning("zlim should be a vector of two elements")
            }
            if (length(zlim) >= 2) {
                obj[obj < zlim[1] | obj > zlim[2]] <- NA
            }
        }
        obj <- as(obj, "SpatialGridDataFrame")
        spplot(obj, ..., as.table = as.table)
    }
    .local(obj, ...)
}

> showMethods("spplot",class="SpatialGridDataFrame",includeDefs=TRUE)
Function: spplot (package sp)
obj="SpatialGridDataFrame"
function (obj, ...) 
spplot.grid(as(obj, "SpatialPixelsDataFrame"), ...)

> showMethods("spplot.grid",class="SpatialPixelsDataFrame",includeDefs=TRUE)

Function "spplot.grid":
 <not an S4 generic function>
> spplot.grid
Error: object 'spplot.grid' not found
> getAnywhere(spplot.grid)
A single object matching ‘spplot.grid’ was found
It was found in the following places
  namespace:sp
with value

function (obj, zcol = names(obj), ..., names.attr, scales = list(draw = FALSE), 
    xlab = NULL, ylab = NULL, aspect = mapasp(obj, xlim, ylim), 
    panel = panel.gridplot, sp.layout = NULL, formula, xlim = bbox(obj)[1, 
        ], ylim = bbox(obj)[2, ], checkEmptyRC = TRUE, col.regions = get_col_regions()) 
{
    if (is.null(zcol)) 
        stop("no names method for object")
    if (checkEmptyRC) 
        sdf = addNAemptyRowsCols(obj)
    else sdf = as(obj, "SpatialPointsDataFrame")
    if (missing(formula)) 
        formula = getFormulaLevelplot(sdf, zcol)
    if (length(zcol) > 1) {
        sdf = spmap.to.lev(sdf, zcol = zcol, names.attr = names.attr)
        zcol2 = "z"
    }
    else zcol2 = zcol
    if (exists("panel.levelplot.raster")) {
        opan <- lattice.options("panel.levelplot")[[1]]
        lattice.options(panel.levelplot = "panel.levelplot.raster")
    }
    scales = longlat.scales(obj, scales, xlim, ylim)
    args = append(list(formula, data = as(sdf, "data.frame"), 
        aspect = aspect, panel = panel, xlab = xlab, ylab = ylab, 
        scales = scales, sp.layout = sp.layout, xlim = xlim, 
        ylim = ylim, col.regions = col.regions), list(...))
    if (all(unlist(lapply(obj@data[zcol], is.factor)))) {
        args$data[[zcol2]] = as.numeric(args$data[[zcol2]])
        if (is.null(args$colorkey) || (is.logical(args$colorkey) && 
            args$colorkey) || (is.list(args$colorkey) && is.null(args$colorkey$at) && 
            is.null(args$colorkey$labels))) {
            if (!is.list(args$colorkey)) 
                args$colorkey = list()
            ck = args$colorkey
            args$colorkey = NULL
            args = append(args, colorkey.factor(obj[[zcol[1]]], 
                ck))
        }
        else args = append(args, colorkey.factor(obj[[zcol[1]]], 
            ck, FALSE))
    }
    ret = do.call(levelplot, args)
    if (exists("panel.levelplot.raster")) 
        lattice.options(panel.levelplot = opan)
    ret
}
<bytecode: 0x7fae5e6b7878>
<environment: namespace:sp>
```

You can see that it supports additional arguments passed via `, list(...))`. As it happens it's therefore fairly easy to add contour lines to a `levelplot` with `contour=TRUE` although that only appears in the Arguments list, but not in the named arguments in the Usage section for `levelplot`. Nonetheless testing in the example on `?levelplot` page shows that it succeeds. Your example is not a particularly good one to illustrate with, since it is so fine-grained and has no pattern of ascending or descending levels. Nonetheless adding `contour=TRUE,` to the arguments to `spplot` does produce black contour lines. (The timestamp is due to lattice code in my Rprofile setup so won't show up on your device).

```
 png(); plot(spplot(s,layout=c(3,1),sp.layout=poly, contour=TRUE,
                  colorkey =list(space = "right"),
                 names.attr = c("a","b","c"))) ; dev.off()
```

[image]

If one gets around to hacking `spplot.grid` or perhaps `sp::panel.gridplot`, then this material from the author of levelplot might be of use:
https://markmail.org/search/?q=list%3Aorg.r-project.r-help+lattice+add+contours+to+levelplot#query:list%3Aorg.r-project.r-help%20lattice%20add%20contours%20to%20levelplot%20from%3A%22Deepayan%20Sarkar%22+page:1+mid:w7q4l7dh6op2lfmt+state:results

Comment: @ 42- Thanks for your answer. I understand that you are trying to help me to see if the additional arguments can be passed to a function. However, the above function 'contour=TRUE' works when you want to plot the raster `s` and overlay contours from raster `s`. However, I want to plot raster `s` but overlay contours from another raster `s1` . I hope you can understand what I mean to say.

Comment: There are lattice functions that let you focus on and then add to existing panels. I don't actually see that you presented an example that makes clear what you require. I think you should start with one simple plot of a single simple raster

Comment: @ 42- I agree with you. Since I created a raster with random values the contours would not be meaningful. Instead of taking random raster I could just take volcano data sets and plot it like `datasets::volcano
        r= raster(volcano)
        extent(r)<-c(-180,180,-90,90)
        plot(s[[1]])
        contour(r,add=T,lwd=0.2,col="red")
        plot(w,add=T,lwd=0.2)
        quiver2D(u = u,v=v,x = lon, y = lat,by=2,scale=0.01,add=T,type="simple")` This is base method of plotting the data. I want spplot to do the same job but for   other rasters as well.